# How to use a function from an external package in the example part of an R file

Tags: r, r-package

I am working on an R package and in the @examples part of my R file I call on `ggplot` from the `ggplot2` package in my example code. I am not using any part of `ggplot2` in my actual package code and so I wasn't sure how to call the `ggplot2` functions.

Originally I thought I would just need to use `ggplot2::ggplot()` but the R CMD Check complained. So I added it to the Imports list in the DESCRIPTION file but then R complained that it shouldn't be in there since I am not using it in my code functions. I then thought to add it to using `@import ggplot2 ggplot` in my .R file but it seemed to complain about that as well.

Can anyone tell me how I should reference external functions in only the example part of my .R file? I tried reading through the R help pages on CRAN as well as Googling for an answer but I guess I wasn't able to find what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packages used for examples only should be listed in 'Suggests:' instead of 'Imports:' in the DESCRIPTION file